# Need help with caliburn Message.Attach when TextBox gets focus

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, attached-properties, caliburn.micro

I have a TextBox that I am setting the focus on using an attached property bound to a property of the view model. The attached property calls "UIElement.Focus()" to set the focus. The problem is when the TextBox receives focus in this manner the "GotFocus" event doesn't fire. I am using Caliburn.Micro's Message.Attach to handle the event. Any ideas?

Here is the TextBox.

```
<TextBox x:Name="Test"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Text="{Binding Test, Converter={StaticResource TestToStringConverter}}"
         AttachedProperties:FocusExtension.IsFocused="{Binding IsTestFocused}"
         cal:Message.Attach="[Event GotFocus] = [Action OnGotFocus($eventargs)]; />
```

Here is the Attached Property (found on SO).

```
public static class FocusExtension
{
    public static bool GetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool) obj.GetValue(IsFocusedProperty);
    }

    public static void SetIsFocused(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(IsFocusedProperty, value);
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsFocusedProperty = 
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("IsFocused", typeof (bool), typeof (FocusExtension),
                                            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged));

    private static void OnIsFocusedPropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var uie = (UIElement)d;

        if ((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            uie.Focus();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you provide the code for the attached property?

Comment: Updated to add the attached property code.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried this myself, and am able to replicate the issue.  I'm not quite sure why this happens, it may have something to do with the user control's (i.e. the views) lifecycle.  One option could be to extend your attached property so that it invokes a verb on your view model at the point at which it calls `uie.Focus()`.

The name of the verb could be a dependency property on your `FocusExtension` attached property, and could be set in the view.

Comment: Pardon my newbiness, but I'm not sure what you mean by "invokes a verb". I'm fairly new to WPF/MVVM.

Comment: That's ok, I just mean to invoke or run a method on your view model class.  In this case, you just want to run the OnGotFocus method, so you could make your attached property generic enough so that the name of the method you wish to run is a property of the attached property.  If that makes sense.

Comment: Would it be possible to show me an short example of what you mean? From what I'm reading it sounds as though the attached property would have knowledge of the viewmodel, but I'm sure I'm probably just misunderstanding.